# Python code modification

Tags: python, maze

I'm trying to program a random maze generator and I'm trying to modify the code mentioned [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_generation#Python). My issue is that I required walls to be represented as a '1' and open walkways to be represented as '0', I've had a play around and I can't seem to find a solution. Any help massively appreciated.

Here's the code for completion

```
from random import shuffle, randrange

def make_maze(w = 16, h = 8):
    vis = [[0] * w + [1] for _ in range(h)] + [[1] * (w + 1)]
    ver = [["|  "] * w + ['|'] for _ in range(h)] + [[]]
    hor = [["+--"] * w + ['+'] for _ in range(h + 1)]

    def walk(x, y):
        vis[y][x] = 1

        d = [(x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1)]
        shuffle(d)
        for (xx, yy) in d:
            if vis[yy][xx]: continue
            if xx == x: hor[max(y, yy)][x] = "+  "
            if yy == y: ver[y][max(x, xx)] = "   "
            walk(xx, yy)

    walk(randrange(w), randrange(h))

    s = ""
    for (a, b) in zip(hor, ver):
        s += ''.join(a + ['\n'] + b + ['\n'])
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(make_maze())
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? At first glance I'd start by modifying `ver` and `hor`, (as in `ver = [["100"] * w + ['1']`, `hor = [["111"] * w + ['1'] for _ in range(h + 1)]`

Answer (score 0):

From the code it looks like 0 represents open spaces.
Just replace the spaces with 0 and the rest with 1 (where ever you find text inside single quotes).